# Regex to match External Links

Tags: php, regex

Please help me improve my Regex to determine External links other than my own website.
E.g- My Website is :   myweb.com. 
And if I also issue subdomains like abc.myweb.com. I want to find link other than these two patterns, So I can prevent External Links.

```
$string = 'www.client.com, www.client.co.in, www.myweb.com, www.abc.myweb.com';
$string = preg_replace('/[https?://]?(www\.)?(?!myweb.com)[^\s/]+(?:/[^\s/]+)*/?/s', '*', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting you are using your delimiter in your expression unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

[This GIST might be useful to you](https://gist.github.com/gruber/249502) taken from this [Daring Fireball post](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Comment: I appreciate your kind efforts. But I'm not able to implement it, as I'm not able to make out how to allow myweb.com & abc.myweb.com while removing rest of the url's, Can you help me further?

Comment: You could use the regex in preg_replace_callback so that you can then compare against a safelist of your own URLS or domains.

Comment: :- Oh Good Idea.. Let me check. But may be my parser is not able to gulp such long Regex, haha. It is showing some parse error. Can you check the last part of the Regex, There are some extra characters I guess. Its long regex so little bit difficult for me to revise

Comment: I just copied and pasted the regex directly from the page, bare in mind you'd need to add the pattern containers (/regex/ or ~regex~).

Comment: Don't use regex for this. This is what parse_url() is for. See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Whilst you're correct, parsing URLs and matching URLs are two different things. In this example @HarshalShah needs to find and match all URLs, not parse them.

Comment: Somebody please provide me with the Regex for that